# Make a query that prints unique pairs?

Tags: sql, database

If you had a relation with the schema `numbers(numtype, ccnum)` where `numtype` and `cpr` together form a key. Then how would you print all pairs of ccnums that have the same numtype? I have thought about something like this

```
SELECT  N1.ccnum AS cc1, N2.ccnum AS cc2
FROM numbers AS N1, numbers AS N2
WHERE N1.numtype = N2.numtype AND N1.ccnum <> N2.ccnum
```

that is, taking the product of two `numbers` relations on the condition given in the `WHERE` clause. The problem(there may be more, so if you see one, please point it out :)) ) is that pairs would be printet twice in the form of (a, b) and (b, a). I only want one of those. How would you write the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `<` rather than `<>`:

```
SELECT N1.ccnum AS cc1, N2.ccnum AS cc2
FROM numbers N1 JOIN
     numbers N2
     ON N1.numtype = N2.numtype AND N1.ccnum < N2.ccnum;
```

Notice that I replace the `,` with `JOIN` and `WHERE` with `ON`.  I would advise you to learn modern, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: Ironically, you misspelt `JOIN` :-)

Comment: Thanks! Does that work no matter the type of `ccnum`?

Comment: Like `ccnum` being an integer, string, etc

Comment: @Dip . . . `<` is defined on all normal types in all databases.  There may be some types -- such as blobs, binary values, records, and arrays (depending on the database) -- where it is not defined, but that would be database-specific.